# max non negative subarray using arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

i am trying to solve this question using arraylist in java
but there is some error. can you tell me what is it that m doing wrong ?
I'm using eclipse indigo and its showing the following error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
>   at hackerrank.maxsub(hackerrank.java:32)
>   at hackerrank.main(hackerrank.java:16)
> ```

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> maxsub(int[] input) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> temp=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int j=0;
    Integer[] sumarray=new Integer[temp.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
    {

        if(input[i]>=0)
        {
            temp.get(j).add(input[i]);
            sumarray[j]=sumarray[j]+input[i];
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }

    }
    int maxsum=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int indexofmaxsum=-1;
    for(int a=0;a<sumarray.length;a++)
    {
        if(sumarray[a]>maxsum)
        {
            maxsum=sumarray[a];
            a=indexofmaxsum;
        }
    }

    return temp.get(indexofmaxsum);
}
```

Comment: what you actually trying to do?

Comment: here `temp` is holding a `arraylist type element` and sadly it is `empty`

Comment: It looks like `temp` is never populated, which means any call to `temp.get()` will throw an error.

Comment: please read this (http://www.javatpoint.com/ArrayList-in-collection-framework) for some basics

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in below statement:

temp.get(j).add(input[i]);

You have created an Arraylist of ArrayList(containing Integers),

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> temp=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

and you haven't added any element(ArrayList of Integers in this case) and trying to get an element using **temp.get(j)**.add(input[i]);

You'll also experience problem here

```
  Integer[] sumarray=new Integer[temp.size()];
```

as you have instantiated an array of size 0(as temp is empty). And

```
  sumarray[j]=sumarray[j]+input[i];
```

this will also cause same exception

Comment: then how do i add the value of input[i] to my arraylist of arraylist ?

Comment: Now you know, where the problem is. Try to figure out a way.
But before that you need to get basics right. Follow a beginner's book and attempt standard algorithms first.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware temp.size is zero before assign to **sumarray**

### Integer[] sumarray=new Integer[temp.size()];

Answer (score 0):

Copy part of your code

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> temp=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int j=0;
    Integer[] sumarray=new Integer[temp.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++)
    {

        if(input[i]>=0)
        {
            temp.get(j).add(input[i]);
            sumarray[j]=sumarray[j]+input[i];
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }

    }
```

1. **temp** seems not populated before used so calling **get(0)** must throws null exception.

   Inner ArrayList instance did not initialized. Call **add()** function will also produce a null pointer exception alert.

Hope this helps you.